# DeleteBy() Algolia

Tags: javascript, delete-file, algolia

I am trying to simply delete an item inside Record in Algolia, but I can not achieve it.(Im working in Javascript)

My structure is the following in each record:
- title
- desc
- date

I want to delete each item in which the date is equal to (for example): 03/04/17
I was trying the following without good results:

```
    var client = algoliasearch('-------', '-------');
    var index = client.initIndex('------');

    index.deleteBy({
      date:'03/04/17',
    }, function(err, content) {
      if (err) throw err;
      alert(JSON.stringify(content));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The date to delete by needs to be specified in the filter parameters and as a [unix timestamp](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/searching/filtering/?language=javascript#filter-by-date).

```
const date = new Date('03/11/17')
const unixDate = date.getTime() / 1000
//...
index.deleteBy({ filter: `date=${unixDate}` }, callback);
```